# vectorising nested for-loops in one line in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I clearly remember an expert code checking for some condition on `i`,`j` and if that evaluated to true, they would mark that in the matrix. Something on the lines shown below. They did this in one line!!! Can someone tell how? What is the most efficient way to code the below lines in Matlab?

```
for i=1:nrows
    for j=1:ncolumns
        if (3*i+4*j>=2 && 6*i-j<=6)
            obstacle(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end
```

**EDIT:**

I had set very easy condition checking on `i,j`. What if things are complicated as edited above?

Comment: Next time you ask a question please provide *ALL* the details to avoid editing the question based on answers provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`logical indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1)** here and take help of **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** for a complicated conditional statement like that -

```
%// Define vectors instead of the scalar iterators used in original code
ii=1:nrows
jj=1:ncolumns

%// Look for logical masks to satisfy all partial conditional statements
condition1 = bsxfun(@plus,3*ii',4*jj)>=2  %//'
condition2 = bsxfun(@plus,6*ii',-1*jj)<=6 %//'

%// Form the complete conditional statement matching logical array
all_conditions = condition1 & condition2

%// Use logical indexing to set them to the prescribed scalar
obstacle(all_conditions) = 1
```

So, the lessons -

1. Replace `3*i+4*j>=2` with `bsxfun(@plus,3*ii',4*jj)>=2` and `6*i-j<=6` with `bsxfun(@plus,6*ii',-1*jj)<=`. Why `bsxfun`? Well, you have two nested loops there with `i` and `j` as the iterators, so you need to form a two-dimensional mask, with one dimension each for those two iterators.
2. Form the complete conditional statement matching logical array by joining those two earlier conditions, as also done in the loopy code with `&&`. You just need to change that to `&` though.
3. Let logical indexing take care of the rest of the story!

Hopefully this must guide you with more complicated loopy codes with conditional statements.

---

**Sidenote:** You can also use **[`ndgrid`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)** or **[`meshgrid`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html)** here to form the 2D conditional/binary array and this could be more intuitive -

```
%// Form the 2D matrix of iterators
[I,J] = ndgrid(1:nrows,1:ncolumns)

%// Form the 2D conditional array and use logical indexing to set all those
obstacle(3*I+4*I>=2 & 6*I-J<=6) = 1
```

Comment: @giffy Absolutely my pleasure! Added a sidenote which could be interesting as well for you!

Comment: If I have a circle condition, `i*i+j*j<=2`, will this work `condition1 = bsxfun(@plus,ii.*ii',jj.*jj)<=2; `?

Comment: @giffy Go with the `ndgrid` approach and use `obstacle(I.*I+J.*J<=2) = 1`.